# Symfony2 plugin for Oh my Zsh in Docker

Tags: symfony, docker, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I trying to install the symfony2 and git plugin for zsh in my docker container.

```
FROM php:7-fpm

# Install Packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim zsh git   
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli zip mbstring 

# Instal Oh my Zsh
RUN bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
RUN sed -i -- 's/robbyrussell/wezm+/g' /root/.zshrc # Other awesome theme: random kafeitu sonicradish wezm+
RUN echo "plugins=(git symfony2)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

But the auto completion does not work. The plugin has not been installed.
Did I miss something?

Comment: Try  `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl zsh git -y` in Dockerfile before install.sh.

Comment: @Nitin It was already done. I just didn't give all the content of my Docker file. I'm going to update my post to give you all the content. But there is no errors in my build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the plugins to get loaded, we need to define the array before including `oh-my-zsh.sh`

So this work:

```
RUN sed -i -- 's/plugins=(git)/plugins=(git symfony2)/g' ~/.zshrc # Add symfony2 plugin
```